# Plotting three rows of one columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

Actually, I didn't really understand how to ask this question. But I have a dataset that look like this

[image: Dataset]

My purpose is to plot the data into multiple classes, that look like this

[image: My Target]

Using this syntax,

```
df_group.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6))
```

I got something like this

[image: What I got]

Actually how to concatenate the room_type, so it can be displayed in one place

I was uploaded my dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EPKvXVKeIUNN6ZMZ739akhP9_ousv2eh/view?usp=sharing)

Is somebody know how to plot into one like that?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unstack:

```
# change 'room_type' to 'neighbor_group' if you prefer the other way.
df_group['price'].unstack('room_type').plot.bar()
```